# Replace an entire tag with a string in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically generate an input field based on the content of a paragraph containing some img tags (i.e. emoticons) and want to replace those images (the entire img tag) with an equivalend string (e.g. **:)**)

I tried the following function and it just does not work as expected.  (Even when I alert the data and use it for replacement)
Moreover, as I have many images I thought there would be a better way to find and replace the entire tag  in a string with jQuery. Any idea?

```
TXT = convertSmiley(TXT);

var convertSmiley = function(data) {
        data = data.replace('<img src="/images/smiley/happy.png" style="margin-bottom:-4px;" height="16" width="16">',':)'); // which does not seem to work

    return data;
}
```

Comment: What's `TXT = convertSmiley(TXT);`, where is it coming from? Btw, if it's not declared before you're missing `var`. Also, can you post html?

Comment: TXT is just an already-declared string! and "of course" it contains a string (like a comment) Btw, thanks for your explanation(s) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

http://jsfiddle.net/gPgr5/

---

**Updated**

for select by the image src, use `$('img[src$="happy.png"]')`

http://jsfiddle.net/gPgr5/1/

Comment: I'm afraid it kind of generic. What if I want to replace different images with different codes like happy.png with :) and sad.png with :(

Comment: @behnum: hope you know how to thanks in stackoverflow. it woks but no vote no accept :P

Answer (score 0):

**Chamika Sandamal** gave you the answer. You should be able to figure it out your self, cmon!

```
var convertSmiley = function(img, smiley) {
    img.replaceWith('<span>'+ smiley +'</span>');
};

convertSmiley($('#happy'), ':)');
```

Comment: Sorry pal, but it does not work as expected. The problem is that I have to provide those arguments that you declared and a piece of raw string is all there is; plus your function looks already weird. Can you pass the "img SELECTOR" from a string into a function?

Comment: You'll have to parse the string then. Take a look at **Flambino** answer. And yes you can pass jQuery objects into functions if that's what you mean http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/LH8bm/1/

Comment: :) alright, but that is, again, a generic approach and a different thing! Replacing img tags with a string. The question was to arm the function to be able to distinguish different images and replace them with a corresponding text. Anyway, Flambino updated his answer and now it works. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

First, go for jQuery's `replaceWith` as described. It's far simpler.

However, if all you have the raw html text, and if you know the names of the emoticon files, you could do something like this:

```
function convertEmoticons(text) {
    var lookup = {
        "happy": ":)",
        "sad":   ":("
        // etc..
    }, regex, name, names = [];

    for( name in lookup ) names.push(name);
    regex = new RegExp('<img src="/images/smiley/(' + names.join("|") + ').png"[^>]*>', "gim");
    return text.replace( regex, function(tag, name) {
        return lookup[name];
    });
}
```

Or you can use parts of the above with `replaceWith`:

```
function convertEmoticons(element) {
    var lookup = {
        "happy": ":)",
        "sad":   ":("
        // etc..
    }, name;
    for( name in lookup )
        $(element).find('img[src$="'+name+'.png"]').replaceWith(lookup[name]);
}
```